# I can't uninstall macports

Tags: uninstallation, macports

I tried to uninstall following this guide: https://guide.macports.org/chunked/installing.macports.uninstalling.html#installing.macports.uninstalling.users

When I put in the last command lines in terminal it does not work and says:

```
zsh: no matches found: /Library/LaunchDaemons/org.macports.*
```

What's the issue here?
I opened /opt/local/bin and there's still files in there.

Comment: SO is a programming Q&A platform and this question is not about programming. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Please delete this.

Answer (score 0):

At the bottom of the page you will find the following note:

> "Depending on which version of MacPorts you have and which ports you have installed, not all of the above paths will exist on your system; this is OK."

Apparently you do not have any files in that directory.  Try removing `/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.macports.*` from the command.